# Persistent history in python cmd module

Tags: python, python-2.7, readline, python-module, python-cmd

Is there any way to configure the [CMD module from Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) to keep a persistent history even after the interactive shell has been closed?

When I press the up and down keys I would like to access commands that were previously entered into the shell on previous occasions that I ran the python script as well as the ones I have just entered during this session.

If its any help cmd uses `set_completer` imported from the [readline module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`readline` automatically keeps a history of everything you enter. All you need to add is hooks to load and store that history.

Use [`readline.read_history_file(filename)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#readline.read_history_file) to read a history file. Use [`readline.write_history_file()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#readline.write_history_file) to tell `readline` to persist the history so far. You may want to use [`readline.set_history_length()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#readline.set_history_length) to keep this file from growing without bound:

```
import os.path
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    readline = None

histfile = os.path.expanduser('~/.someconsole_history')
histfile_size = 1000

class SomeConsole(cmd.Cmd):
    def preloop(self):
        if readline and os.path.exists(histfile):
            readline.read_history_file(histfile)

    def postloop(self):
        if readline:
            readline.set_history_length(histfile_size)
            readline.write_history_file(histfile)
```

I used the [`Cmd.preloop()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.preloop) and [`Cmd.postloop()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.postloop) hooks to trigger loading and saving to the points where the command loop starts and ends.

If you don't have `readline` installed, you could simulate this still by adding a [`precmd()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.precmd) and record the entered commands yourself.